# How to save a CoreGraphics Drawing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, save, core-graphics

I want to make an application where the user can draw on the screen and then save their drawings. Below is my `UIView` draw code:

```
import UIKit

class DrawView: UIView {


    var lines: [Line] = [] // Line is a custom class, shown below
    var lastPoint: CGPoint!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        lastPoint = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var newPoint = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint!))
        lastPoint = newPoint
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextBeginPath(context)
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
        for line in lines {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
        }
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

Code for Line class:

```
import UIKit

class Line {

    var start: CGPoint
    var end: CGPoint

    init(start _start: CGPoint, end _end: CGPoint ) {
        start = _start
        end = _end

    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to save this drawing using `NSUserDefaults`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To capture a view, you can use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` and `drawHierarchy`:

```
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: view.bounds).image { _ in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

---

To save it in `UserDefaults`, you could:

```
if let data = image.pngData() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "snapshot")
}
```

To retrieve it from `UserDefaults`, you could:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "snapshot"), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
    ...
}
```

---

Personally, I wouldn't be inclined to store images in `UserDefaults`. I'd save it to persistent storage. For example, to save it into the Application Support folder you could:

```
do {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("test.png")

    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomicWrite)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //I would recomend you to save line on touches end
     override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        save()
    }

    func save() {

        var data : NSMutableData=NSMutableData()

        var archiver=NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
        archiver.encodeObject(lines, forKey:"classLine")
        archiver.finishEncoding()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "shape")
    }


    class func loadSaved() {
        if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("shape") as? NSData {

            var unarchiver :NSKeyedUnarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data);

            var line : Line = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("classLine") as Line!

        }

    }



}


class Line : NSObject {

    var start: CGPoint
    var end: CGPoint

    init(start _start: CGPoint, end _end: CGPoint ) {
        start = _start
        end = _end

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

            aCoder.encodeCGPoint(start, forKey: "start")
            aCoder.encodeCGPoint(end, forKey: "end")

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        start  = aDecoder.decodeCGPointForKey("start")
        end  = aDecoder.decodeCGPointForKey("end")


 }
}
```

Comment: You welcome I have made some update try it let mw know if you get any issue.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Before NSKeyedArchiving It is needed to be encoded and also before unarchiving it is needed to decoded. I liked your answer saving to PNG file and retrieving back the PNG file

Comment: Ok so by default it is not NSObject. you are right. I will edit my answer